# Остановка процесса не зная PID в Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Подскажите пожалуйста, запускаю с помощью cron несколько процессов в ubuntu server, делаю так (пример):

```
30 15 28 * * команда 1
30 16 28 * * команда 2
```

теперь задача, нужно задать в том же cron завершение процесса 1 к примеру в:

```
30 17 27 * *
```

При этом процесс 2 должен работать дальше без остановки, PID процесса неизвестен, COMMAND у них одинаковый (например ffmpeg), то есть команда:

```
30 17 28 * * killall ffmpeg
```

не подходит, так как она завершит оба процесса.
Подскажите как решить эту проблемку, заранее спасибо!

Comment: А если сделать ссылку на/скопировать ffmpeg и первым процессом запускать копию, скажем ffmpeg-first?

Comment: а можно подробней? честно говоря не понял что вы имеете ввиду

Comment: installerero имел ввиду, что в папке `/usr/bin` или где там у вас лежит ffmpeg сделать символическую или жесткую ссылку на ffmpeg и назвать ее например ffmpeg-first, т.е. по сути просто делать 2 ffmpeg с разными именами и тогда killall убивать требуемую

Answer (score 7):

Всем спасибо, решил вопрос запуском этих команд от разных юзеров, тогда команда killall ffmpeg убивает процесс только этого юзера, а остальные работают дальше.

Answer (score 4):

можно отправлять процесс в *background* оператором `&`, а его идентификатор, сохранившийся в переменной `$!`, записывать в файл (с произвольным именем).

откуда в нужный момент его можно прочитать и передать аргументом программе `kill`.

пример:

```
минуты1 * * * * команда & echo $! > /tmp/команда.pid
минуты2 * * * * kill $(cat /tmp/команда.pid) &>/dev/null
```

---

в случае, если `команда` — это последовательный запуск нескольких программ, связанных `;`, `&&` или `||`, то, для правильной работы оператора `&`, такую составную команду надо «завернуть» в подоболочку (*subshell*) с помощью скобок:

```
минуты1 * * * * (составная команда) & echo $! > /tmp/команда.pid
```